# Symfony2: How to generate default entity for every user

Tags: symfony

I am new to Symfony2, so please be kind to my stupid question.

I have User and Collection entities. User has one-to-many relationship with Collection.

How can I generate 1 default collection for every User? So when user registers, he already has 1 pre-defined collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [custom User class](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-3-create-your-user-class), use the constructor to add a Collection:

```php
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    private $collections;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->collections = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->collections->add(new Collection());
    }
}
```